# CRM Dynamics. E-mail. Workflow

Tags: email, dynamics-crm, workflow

My process generates an automatic letter to the user within a single entity. You need to add a field value from another related entity to the letter. Please help me how to do this?

Entity 1 - Opportunity;
Entity 2 - Organization to which the opportunity belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other activities (Email, Appointment, etc), Letter is a different concept. It won’t generate a document, it is simply a note or task as a placeholder to generate Letter using Letter template (Mail merge in old days) - so respective Person can generate it in CRM UI, print it and send it offline. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/165094/questions-about-workflow-create-letter/402940)

That being said, you can generate a word template with any parent and it’s related entities, compose and save it for later use like Letter use case. [Read more](https://powerobjects.com/tips-and-tricks/how-to-create-a-microsoft-word-template-in-microsoft-dynamics-365/)